# filename of binary field not worked , it is encoded odoo10

Tags: filenames, wizard, odoo-10

in my wizard `.py` , I have:

datas = fields.Binary('File')
filename = fields.Char('File Name')

And in `.xml` File:

```
<field name="datas" filename="filename" />
<field name="filename" invisible="1"/>
```

But in my view form it gives error:

> filename appears encoded.

How I can correct this issue?

[image]

Comment: Have you find something ?

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `filename` field above the `datas` field in your XML. You may want to make the `filename` field visible until it is working so you can ensure the name is storing there correctly.